how to implement a .Net Maui CollectionView layout with vertical groups and horizontal items
i am trying to achieve a certain look within an application that shows items in a categorized way.
From what i have learned is that the CollectionView allows us to exactly do this and i have successfully used it in various layouts. The problem is that there is exactly one layout that i am trying to achieve that i could not find described anywhere and hence need help/guidance with.
The CollectionView allows us to go for either a grid or linear layout and allows us to have grouping on objects. What i want to achieve is that the items of a group are shown as a linear horizontal collection while the categories are put one after another in a vertical way. (like shown in the amazing drawing attached).

I have tried all possible combinations of the CollectionView (that i know of) and could not achieve this and thus am pondering whether at this point i would have to create this thing entirely manually or to have simply multiple CollectionView instances be created for each Category.
Any help would be appreciated.
P.S: quiet new to .Net maui and mobile dev. but do have xaml knowledge.
I have tried to have one main collection view with isgrouped=true and a groupheaderlayout. then as item template i tried to create an another collectionview which takes the group again and works as a normal horizontal collectionview but it did not work.

I have managed to do it by doing the following:

in the ItemsGroupModel declare a list of the same object type and populate it with the original one.


public class AnimalsCategory : List<Animal>
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
    public AnimalsCategory(string groupName, List<Animal> animals, string) : base(animals)
    {
        Animals = new List<Animal>(animals);
    }
}



The ViewModel is quiet the basic one and follows the recommended .Net Maui style (Note: i am using the Mvvm Toolkit for the ObservableProperty and sitting the property's value and not the fields!)


public partial class AnimalsViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    List<ShopItemsCategory> categories;
    
    public AnimalsViewModel(DataService ds)
    {
        Categories = ds.GetAnimalsInCategories();
    }
}



I made sure to access the newly defined property "Animals" in the XAML inside the sub-list.


<RefreshView Grid.Row="1">
  <ScrollView>
      <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
          <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:AnimalsCategory ">
                  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                      <Label Text="{Binding GroupName}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="28"/>
                      <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}" ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" Background="Transparent" Margin="5">
                          <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                              <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Animal">
                                  <Frame CornerRadius="20"
                                                Margin="5,5,5,5"
                                                HasShadow="True"
                                                BackgroundColor="#FEF6FF"
                                                   WidthRequest="150"
                                                   HeightRequest="200">
                                      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
                                           Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                          <Image Source="{Binding Image}" 
                                            Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="60" 
                                             WidthRequest="60" 
                                             Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                                          <Line Stroke="LightGray" X2="300" 
                                            StrokeThickness="2"/>
                                          <Label Text="{Binding Name}" > 
                                            Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                             FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                              VerticalOptions="Center"
                                             HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                           <Label Text="{Binding > 
                                        Description}" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                                      </StackLayout>
                                  </Frame>
                              </DataTemplate>
                          </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                      </CollectionView>
                  </StackLayout>
              </DataTemplate>
          </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      </CollectionView>
  </ScrollView>
</RefreshView>


